# Display sum of values for qcut() bin label

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum a column of values based upon the binning of another column.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data_file.csv",  na_values=' ')
hincp = df.HINCP.dropna()
grouping = pd.qcut(hincp, 3, labels=["low", "medium", "high"])
```

I want to sum the values of another column `df['WGTP']` based on the "low", "medium", and "high" bins and display the count for each bin. Like so:

```
         WGTP_count
low           12300
medium         3455
high          65500
```

(Hypothetical numbers) Would I use groupby? Value_counts? I really have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: `df['WGTP'].value_counts()`

Comment: You should replace `count` in the title with wording that matches what you want (ie `sum the values`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the code more generic so it can serve others, I'll let you adapt the column names to match your example:

- `to_bins` is the column on which you create the quantiles with `.qcut`
- `to_sum` are the values you want to sum up based on your quantiles

Initial df:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['to_bins', 'to_sums']
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30], [1, 10],[2, 20], [3, 30]], columns=cols)
```

Output:

```
   to_bins to_sums
0       1      10
1       2      20
2       3      30
3       1      10
4       2      20
5       3      30
```

Creating quantiles with `qcut` and assigning to `bins` column:

```
df['bins'] = pd.qcut(df.to_bins, 3, labels=['low', 'medium', 'high']).values
```

Output:

```
   to_bins  to_sums    bins
0        1       10     low
1        2       20  medium
2        3       30    high
3        1       10     low
4        2       20  medium
5        3       30    high
```

Summing up values as per those bins (`.reset_index()` is used to convert the output of a groupby back into a dataframe you can further manipulate if you want):

```
df.groupby(['bins'])['to_sums'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     bins  to_sums
0     low      20
1  medium      40
2    high      60
```